# Not able to see .metadata in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse

Not able to see .metadata in Eclipse Indigo workspace even after the hidden files option is unchecked.
How to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you double-check that you are in fact looking in the correct workspace folder

Comment: Is this Linux or Mac or Windows?

Comment: Windows and I am looking in correct workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse workspace does not represent directly the file system of the directory, but shows a set of projects (that are by default stored in the workspace folder).

The .metadata folder is never shown in the Eclipse workspace, as it always contains important metadata (e.g. it contains the set of imported project, all Preferences, etc.).

If for any reason you need to open the metadata folder, do not use Eclipse but any external file browser; on the other hand, I would be very careful with the editing, as it contains some file whose changes could corrupt your entire workspace in the IDE.

Comment: I see that .metadata folder from explorer in my system. I was not able to see the same on other machine.

Comment: Again, the Eclipse file structure views does not show the contents of the underlying file system but the Eclipse-model of it that should never contain the .metadata folder. Maybe if you have imported the .metadata folder as a project, it is possible to load it (again, not recommended), or you were using a special view that showed the file system directly, and not its eclipse representation.